# How to fix fetching JSON data on inside of loop with limit number?

Tags: javascript, json

There is something bothers me.
I'm trying to understand this output in console, take a look

[image: loop and json data]

listdata is a global variable.

I can use listdata.orders[x].id_order to return any numbers without errors.

Then I use for() to make a list and it gave me an error that doesn't make sense =/

**EDIT: It needs to be limited as 9 items, not complete as data.length**

Comment: Do you have at least 10 order objects in `listdata`?  If not, try changing the `for` loop to `for (var i = 0; i < listdata.orders.length; i++) {`

Comment: try replace condition to `i < listdata.orders.length`

Comment: What does `listdata.orders` look like? What happens if you try `listdata.orders[9]`?

Comment: @AdeelZafarSoomro varies, it can be 5, 9, 12 or 25, Im using 9 to limit.

Comment: *it can be 5, 9, 12 or 25,* And you don't see the problem there? If it's `5` what do you expect to happen with `listdata.orders[5]` or higher?

Comment: @Ivan In that case, you should only iterate up to the length of orders.  Change your condition as suggested by vp_arth.

Comment: @MattBurland  it works, but how to set 9 as limit? I don't want to show it more than 50 as orders.length

Comment: `i < Math.min(listdata.orders.length, 9)`  or `i < listdata.orders.length && i < 9`

Comment: Then do something like `Math.min(listdata.orders.length,10)` as your limit. Then it will loop up to either `9` or `listdata.orders.length-1`, whichever is smaller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
listdata.orders.forEach(function (order) {
    console.log(order.id_order);
});
```

To limit the iteration to 9 orders.

**Method 1:**

```
listdata.orders.slice(0, 9).forEach(function (order) {
    console.log(order.id_order);
});
```

**Method 2:**

```
listdata.orders.some(function (order, index) {
    if (index > 9) {
        return true;
    }
    console.log(order.id_order);
});
```

Comment: It works, but it fetched more than 50 items, do you know how to set limit as 9 items? edit this answer if you can.

Comment: @Ivan: It would have been better if you had stated that in your original question.

Comment: I updated the answer with a different solution. This should be what you are looking for.

Comment: For some reason using forEach wont display in some div, until I used for(); with Math.min that worked at everything.

Comment: That makes me wonder what the reason could possibly be. `forEach` is just like `for` but with some _syntactical sugar_.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = listData.orders; //All Orders
for(var b in a) 
{
var c = [b];
 console.log(c,c.id_order); //Know the values...
}
```

Comment: Never iterate arrays as objects. Any third-side library can add iterable method to `Array.prototype` and you will get it too.